# Implementation of A star algorithm

Tags: algorithm, arraylist, hashmap, a-star

Can the A star algorithm implemented using HashMaps instead of ArrayLists?

Comment: A* Algorithm uses HashMap [or HashSet] already - for storing "closed" nodes. It uses many more data structures. If you want a good answer - you will have to be much more specific. I don't believe there is any indication of `ArrayList` in the original algorithm's pseudo-code, so I believe you are asking about specific implementation - so for a good answer, we need much more details on this implementation.

Comment: It never used ArrayLists, except perhaps in particularly lame implementations.

Comment: A star algorithm is not related to any data structure in particular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, A star is not related to any specific data structure. I implemented it using an Array list and Sorted List( for storing the open nodes in sorted order). You can implement it according to your need

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are talking about is a heap, or say a priority queue. The best-first search approach requires you pick the node from the open set with the least cost. A heap allows to do  O(log N) insertion and look up the current best node at O(1).